# My code is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem with this code, I am not sure what is wrong.  Essentially it is supposed to take input from user, set it to a variable, then write a string.  It is not writing anything out after I try typing in a name.

Hello, the purpose of this site is for process enhancement for searching for POU Kit Parts:

```
    <form id="form1">
    <p>enter name:  <input name="name" type="text" size="20"></p></form>
    <p><button onclick="outputname()"> Submit</button></p>

    <script>
    function outputname(){
        var x,name,a,b,answer,y;
        x=document.getElementById("form1");
        y=x.elements["name"].value;
        document.write("hello" +y+ );
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is an extra `+` in your statement which is throwing a syntax error.

change

```
document.write("hello" +y+ );
```

to

```
document.write("hello" + y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessary `+` sign in your `document.write` function.

```js
function outputname() {
  var x, name, a, b, answer, y;
  x = document.getElementById("form1");
  y = x.elements["name"].value;
  document.write("hello " + y);
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <p>enter name: <input name="name" type="text" size="20"></p>
</form>
<p><button onclick="outputname()">Submit</button></p>
```